# Bake a texture WITHOUT doing UV Unwrapping?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I am a SketchUp user by trade, but one thing Sketchup can't do is export UV texture maps for objects such as you have to use for .obj fils in something like Tabletop Simulator, which will only import one model file and one texture file - so I have to use Blender. (Just to be absolutely clear as to my terms by 'unwrapped texture map' I mean something like this wherein a complex object is unwrapped onto a single plane and all the various materials and textures are shown in an 'unwrapped' state so they can be wrapped around a model and make it look painted)

So: if I export my Sketchup file as a Collada file it imports into Blender just fine - my textures are all in place, the model looks like it did when I exported it, and I am perfectly capable of lighting and rendering it. But that's not what I want to do - I want to make that flat, square UV texture map. Unfortunately, the UV maps looks like any other UV map before you unwrap it - a big squiggly mess.

SO the obvious thing to do is to select my model, go the edit mode, select everything, do a SMartUV unwrap - same as I would for anything else in Blender.

Unfortunately, that immediately ruins all my textures. Everything becomes instantly distorted and all my careful texture dimension work goes out the window. I've got a UV map, but now all my textures are wrong.

So there was a suggestion that all I need do is to 'bake' the textures as they were imported, but that seems to come with its own host of problems, and all the tutorials I can find are all about baking procedurally generated Blender materials - not textures imported externally from another program.

**TO SUMMATE MY ISSUE**

I have a model built in sketchup. The model contains *multiple* different textures - like a house with brick walls, window glass, roof tiles etc. I can import this into Blender as a Collada file, but the moment I unwrap the UV, all the textures in my model instantly distort. (E.G. a wall with many bricks sees the brick texture expand so that each brick is nine feet long and blurry as heck).

How can I unwrap my model without affecting the texture size. Alternatively, is there a way I can bake everything into one nice square/rectangular texture map for use in a game WITHOUT having to unwrap the UV?

Can anyone here help me? I want to take my imported model and create a texture map preferably without having to completely repaint the entire model. What are my options?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can create a new UV Map in the Object Data panel > UV Maps, and use it as the UV that will receive the bake

Comment: The moment I create any UV maps my texture scaling is instantly destroyed. The model does not import with a UV map - one has to be created first, and therein lies the issue. If I create a new UV map in Object Data, go to Render Properties - > Cycles - Bake, I just get an error message about needing a UV map.

Comment: could you please share one of your objects? https://pasteall.org/blend/